# How I can get next page users from Azure AD graph api?

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the AAD Graph Client Library to query the users from AAD as follows:

```
IPagedCollection<IUser> usersA = activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result;
AzureGraphUsers.AddRange(usersA.CurrentPage);
```

These calls give me 100 users per page (by default)

How can I get next page users using Graph Client Library in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
do{
    pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
}while(pagedCollection != null && pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable);
```

By the way,

> We strongly recommend that you use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) instead of
>   Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)
>   resources. Our development efforts are now concentrated on Microsoft Graph and no further enhancements are planned for Azure AD Graph API. There are a very limited number of scenarios for which Azure AD Graph API might still be appropriate; for more information, see the [Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) blog post and [Migrate Azure AD Graph apps to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-overview).

Reference:

[C# (CSharp) ActiveDirectoryClient Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/ActiveDirectoryClient/-/php-activedirectoryclient-class-examples.html)